# PYTHON ghostscript loop only executes once

Tags: python, pdf, path

I have a folder called pdfs. I first obtain a list of the files and print them:

```
import ghostscript, os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

def get_files(path):
    input_files = [f for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]
    return input_files

def pdf2jpeg(pdf_input_path, jpeg_output_path):
    args = ["pdf2jpeg", # actual value doesn't matter
            "-dNOPAUSE",
            "-sDEVICE=jpeg",
            "-dJPEGQ=95",
            "-r600x600",
            "-sOutputFile=" + jpeg_output_path,
            pdf_input_path]
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_files = get_files("pdfs")
    # pdf2jpeg("pdfs/test1.pdf", "jpgs/test1.jpg")
    for input_file in input_files:
        input_file_name = str("pdfs/"+str(input_file))
        output_file_name = str('jpgs/'+str(input_file).replace(" ", "_").replace("pdf", "jpg"))#split(".")[0]
        print input_file_name
        print output_file_name
        # pdf2jpeg(input_file_name, output_file_name)
```

OUTPUT:

```
pdfs/test1 (5th copy).pdf
jpgs/test1_(5th_copy).jpg
pdfs/test1 (copy).pdf
jpgs/test1_(copy).jpg
pdfs/test1 (4th copy).pdf
jpgs/test1_(4th_copy).jpg
pdfs/test1 (3rd copy).pdf
jpgs/test1_(3rd_copy).jpg
pdfs/test1 (another copy).pdf
jpgs/test1_(another_copy).jpg
```

Also when i execute `pdf2jpeg("pdfs/test1.pdf", "jpgs/test1.jpg")` the code works and I get the converted jpg.

Now when I want to loop through the list and uncoment the last line:`pdf2jpeg(input_file_name, output_file_name)`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_files = get_files("pdfs")
    # pdf2jpeg("pdfs/test1.pdf", "jpgs/test1.jpg")
for input_file in input_files:
    input_file_name = str("pdfs/"+str(input_file))
    output_file_name = str('jpgs/'+str(input_file).replace(" ", "_").replace("pdf", "jpg"))#split(".")[0]
    print input_file_name
    print output_file_name
    pdf2jpeg(input_file_name, output_file_name)
```

I GET THIS ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gsPdf2Jpg.py", line 28, in <module>
    pdf2jpeg(input_file_name, output_file_name)
  File "gsPdf2Jpg.py", line 17, in pdf2jpeg
    ghostscript.Ghostscript(*args)
  File "/home/trackstarz/prohealth/phenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 157, in Ghostscript
    stderr=kw.get('stderr', None))
  File "/home/trackstarz/prohealth/phenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghostscript/__init__.py", line 72, in __init__
    rc = gs.init_with_args(instance, args)
  File "/home/trackstarz/prohealth/phenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ghostscript/_gsprint.py", line 177, in init_with_args
    raise GhostscriptError(rc)
ghostscript._gsprint.GhostscriptError: limitcheck
```

I went through and changed the loop to only go through individual input_files[0], input_files[1] and they work, the moment I loop them all they stop working. The only thing I can think of is that I have to clear something from the memory, or disconnect from the file. I am just taking wild guesses here.

Comment: check the indentation, with this one, you're only execute the function `pdf2jpeg()` with the last (leaking) items of the loop

Comment: @PRMoureu I was thinking the same, but shouldn't it still work for the last `input_file_name` and `outpuy_file_name` values?

Comment: yep, this doesn't explain the error, but i refered to the title 'loop only executes once'

Comment: Sorry that was just a typo when I copied over. the first time i run the loop without it i can see the paired values print.